# Part of JSON from String to Integer

Tags: string, postgresql, casting, integer

I have a text field with JSON structure in my Postgres v10.8 DB.
I need to grab a value inside the config and cast it to a whole number. (values are in format like this 0.0, 1.0, 2.0) It's never 1.5 so it should be possible to turn it into whole numbers.

With this select i can grab the value i need but i don't know how i can turn the results from this into a whole number?

```
select coalesce(cast(tb.config_exit as json)->> 'exit_time_tenant' , '') as exit_time from table tb
```

When i try to say cast('1.0' as Integer) i get this ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "1.0"

This works but it's probably not a good solution?

```
cast(substring('1.0' from '([0-9]+)(.{1})') as Integer)
```

Comment: Please put your sample JSON data

Comment: {"cd":"09","mv_er_cd":"060","exit_time_tenant":"4.0","ex":"4.0","earliest_date":"2026-09-30","earliest_date_mv":[],"mb_in":null,"mb_out":null}

Answer (score 0):

You should convert `tb.config_exit :: json ->> 'exit_time_tenant'` between parentheses and then convert to decimal

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8dfb4a8a94e2fa9af604f84d56539864)

```sql
select 
  (tb.config_exit :: json ->> 'exit_time_tenant') :: decimal :: int as exit_time 
from 
  "table" tb
```

Comment: I have the same problem with decimal as with text. Im not allowed to send 4.0 as decimal. I has to be 4 as int. The program that handles my output is expecting an Int.

Comment: If you need to convert to int add `::int` after convert decimal (I updated post)